# Hyperbolic tangents as a dense subset of smooth functions satisfying certain conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Edit:** The original question contained some errors that lead to some comments and answers that do not apply anymore. I thank those that took time to read the question and pointed out the errors. I tried to be more precise this time.

Let $V$ be the set of smooth (infinitely differentiable) functions $f:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy the following conditions:

- $f(0)=0$
- $f'(x)\geq 0, \forall x$
- $f''(x)\leq 0$, $\forall x$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)$ is a real number

I'd like to find a dense subset $A\subseteq V$ (w.r.t. to the $L^2$ norm, say), where $A$ is a family of functions depending only on some real-valued parameters.

My first guess was to take the family $\{a\tanh(sx): a,s\geq0\}$, but after some numerical computations I saw it doesn't work: e.g. $\arctan(x)\in V$ cannot be arbitrarily approximated by functions of the form $a\tanh(sx)$.

My questions are:

1. Can we find a dense $A$ as described above (depending only on some real parameters).
2. In case that the answer to the previous question is "yes", can the hyperbolic tangents family I described be easily modified to become a dense subset?
3. What if we change the definition domain from $[0,+\infty)$ to $[0,B]$ for some real number $B>0$? Does this compactness condition help in being able to find a dense subset?

Comment: But functions with $f''(x) > 0$ do not form a vector space, multiplying a function $f \in V$ by a negative scalar reverses the inequality. Do you perhaps mean $V$ to be some sort of a cone?

Comment: @BartoszMalman: You're right. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The following argument has been rendered moot by an edit to the question.

The claim is vacuously true; $V$ is empty.

From the limit condition at $\infty$, there is some $u>0$ with $f(u)>0$. Then, by the Mean Value Theorem, there is some $v\in (0,u)$ with $f'(v) = \frac{f(u)}{u}>0$. Now, for all $x>v$, $f(x)\ge f(v) + (x-v)f'(v)$, which goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$. Our function, which was supposed to have a finite limit at $\infty$, instead goes to $\infty$. There's nothing there - including that $f_{a,s}$ is never in $V$. In fact, for positive $a$ and $s$, the second derivative of $f_{a,s}$ is negative on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh, god... you're absolutely right. The inequality of the second derivative should be the other way around... I already edited the question.